# How to make abbrev expand on symbol, not on word?

Tags: abbrev

I have something like

```
(define-abbrev-table 'c++-mode-abbrev-table '(("string" "std::string" nil 0)))
```

in my `.abbrev_defs`. However, when I input `to_string`, the `string` still gets expanded into `std::string` results in `to_std::string`.

How to make abbrev treat the `string` in definition as a symbol thus expand it only when I input a *symbol* "string"?

Answer (score 1):

Abbrev is about words, by default. The default expansion function uses function `abbrev--before-point`, which looks for word boundaries.

1. But you can define your own `abbrev-expand-function`.  See node [Abbrev Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Abbrev-Expansion.html).
2. Or if you set the syntax of character `_` to word-constituent (`w`) instead of symbol-constituent (`_`) then the `s` in `to_string` will not be on a word boundary, so the default expansion will do what you want here.
   See the Elisp manual, node [Syntax Class Table](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html).